# How to search content in files in Powershell

Tags: powershell, search, select-string

I want to make a dynamic function that searches for the requested $ErrorCode within the files inputted and eventually copy the files with the error to another folder.

Right now, my code takes only one file and returns the sentence of where the $Error_Code was found.  I want to search through multiple files and return the name of the file that have the $ErrorCode.

```
function SearchError{

    Param (
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $SourcePath,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $SourceFile,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $ErrorCode,
        [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $FileType
       # [Parameter (Mandatory=$true)] [STRING] $DestPath


        )  
    $TargetPath = "$($SourcePath)\$($SourceFile)"
    #Return $TargetPath

    $DestinationPath = "$($DestPath)"
    #Return $DestinationPath 


    #foreach($error in $TargetPath) {

    Get-ChildItem $TargetPath | Select-String -pattern $ErrorCode 

}
SearchError
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `Select-String`'s output objects - which are of type [`[Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MatchInfo]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.powershell.commands.matchinfo) - have a `.Path` property that reflects the input file path.
- Adding the `-List` switch to `Select-String` makes it stop searching after the first match in the file, so you'll get exactly 1 output object for each file in which at least 1 match was found.

Therefore, the following outputs only the paths of the input files in which at least 1 match was found:

```
Get-ChildItem $TargetPath |
  Select-String -List -Pattern $ErrorCode | ForEach-Object Path
```

Note: `-Pattern` supports an *array* of regex patterns, so if you define your `$ErrorCode` parameter as `[string[]]`, files that have *any one* of the patterns will match; use `-SimpleMatch` instead of `-Pattern` to search by *literal substrings* instead.

---

Re:

> eventually copy the files with the error to another folder

Simply appending `| Copy-Item -Destination $DestPath` to the above command should do.

Re:

> I want to search through multiple files

Depending on your needs, you can make your `$SourcePath` and `$SourceFile` parameters *array*-valued (`[string[]]`) and / or pass *wildcard expressions* as arguments.